# HttpURLConnection returns 404 when called from an IntentService

Tags: android

I am attempting to build an IntentService that uploads files using a REST Api.

I am able to start the IntentService from my main Activity, and the IntentService can pass a message back to the Activity so I know the IntentService is working.

My issue is when I run this code:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {      
    // do the uploading stuff       
    try {           
        URL url = new URL(this.url + fileName);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        BufferedInputStream buffInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        BufferedOutputStream buffOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        HttpUtils.copyBufferStream(buffInputStream, buffOutputStream);

        if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            BufferedInputStream responseBufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            byte[] body = HttpUtils.readStream(responseBufferedInput);                          
            result = HttpUtils.convertBytesToString(body);              
            Log.e("Result:", result);
        }else{
            Log.e("conn.getResponseCode()", Integer.toString(conn.getResponseCode()));
        }       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                                       
}
```

in the IntentService onHandleIntent method, I always get a 404 (or FileNotFoundException when not checking conn.getResponseCode()).

Calling the exact same code in my main Activity, uploads the file and completes successfully.

I have no idea why this is happening? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try printing the URL you're trying to open, you will probably find out that there's something wrong with it...maybe it's just a missing slash ;-)

404 is the HTTP error for not found..meaning that the URL is invalid on that server.

Comment: Good point. If the URL was malformed at all or not properly encoded this would definitely return a 404. In this case the url is exactly as it should be. I've tested the same url in the same HttpURLConnection code in my main Activity, and also in a REST Api console in a browser and it works fine.

Comment: Doh! Turns out the url was actually wrong, and there was in fact a missing slash; Thanks!